# defining linear equations in Java

Tags: java, linear-programming, lpsolve

I am trying to implement a paper and I am facing problem while representing linear equations mentioned in the paper. I am using LPsolve (linear problem solver) to solve the equations. But not able to represent some equations in Java so that LPSOLVE can resolve. Anyone with expertise in this please do help me.

paper i am trying to implement is http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dshahaf/kdd2010-shahaf-guestrin.pdf and equations are mentioned in section 2.2.1

Comment: Please add the code you've tried and any error messages it generates.

Comment: Is the problem with formulating linear equations, or with lpsolve input? If the former, I think it may be a mathematics problem rather than a programming problem. If the latter, please add a link to the documentation for the interface you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can tell, you seem to have trouble figuring out o implementing some functions that would represent how certain mathematical functions work. It doesn't sound like you've run into an error, so I'll write down a few tips I can think of.

First off, check if the functions you are looking for already exist in the basic library by taking a look in the documentation. Maybe it doesn't state it exactly like you want, but perhaps some of the functionality is there.

http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Java/docs/api/

If you can't find everything you want, then you've got two options. One is to program the functions you desire yourself, and the other is to use another fleshed out Java library such as Colt which has many features.

http://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/